# webservice with multiple parameter

Tags: apache-axis

I create a webservice with axis2 like that：

```
public void setWeather(@WebParam(name = "weather") Weather weather,
                        @WebParam(name = "city") String city,
                        @WebParam(name = "country") String country) {
               System.out.println("weather:" + weather);
               System.out.println("city:" + city);
               System.out.println("country:" + country);
               this.weather = weather;
     }
```

Then I send a soap message:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
     <soapenv:Body>
               <ns2:setWeather xmlns:ns2="http://service.pojo.sample">
                        <ns2:weather>
                                 <ns1:forecast  xmlns:ns1="http://data.pojo.sample/xsd">rain</ns1:forecast>
                                 <ns1:howMuchRain xmlns:ns1="http://data.pojo.sample/xsd">102.3</ns1:howMuchRain>
                                 <ns1:rain xmlns:ns1="http://data.pojo.sample/xsd">true</ns1:rain>
                                 <ns1:temperature xmlns:ns1="http://data.pojo.sample/xsd">20.3</ns1:temperature>
                        </ns2:weather>
                        <ns2:country>china</ns2:country>
               </ns2:setWeather>
     </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And I receive 
weather:Weather [temperature=20.3, forecast=rain, rain=true, howMuchRain=102.3]
city:china
country:null

ns2:country node have been assigned null, why this happens?